# CSS styling and jquery adding/removing hidden class stops working after displaying data from database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have an html page styled as shown. When I click the Create New List button, the pink div appears. The All Lists div is shown in orange. Currently, a new user has signed up and not created any lists. On clicking the categories button, the All Lists div is hidden, and the categories div is shown (done using a hidden class and jquery). The same thing happen's after clicking the To Do's button (a third div is shown and the remaining 2 are hidden).

[image]

```
//php code for the Categories button. The other two buttons have similar versions.

$('#menu_categories').click( function() {
        if (!$('#all_lists').hasClass("hidden")) 
        {
            $('#all_lists').addClass("hidden");
            $('#categories').removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else if (!$('#to_dos').hasClass("hidden")) 
        {
            $('#to_dos').addClass("hidden");
            $('#categories').removeClass("hidden");
        }
    });
```

This is the yellow category div that appears after clicking the Categories button. The All Lists div is hidden.

[image]

The problems arise when a new list has been created. Once I enter text into the textarea and click Create, the data is stored in a MySQL table and all the data in the table is echoed inside the All Lists div.

Code for sending data to the database after clicking the Create button:

```
<?php
require 'PHP/database.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit_create_list']))
{
    $list_name = $_POST['create_list_text'];
    if (!empty($list_name)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO list_names(ln_user_id, list_name) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_SESSION['userid'], $list_name);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Refresh:0");
    }   
}

?>
```

Code for echoing the data in the database back to the All Lists div:

```
<div class="inner_list_box"  id="all_lists">
            <?php 
            require 'PHP/database.php';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM list_names WHERE ln_user_id= '{$_SESSION['userid']}';";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
                echo "You haven't created any lists yet :(";
            } 
            else{
                echo("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th></tr>");
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo "<tr><td><a href =''>"; 
                    echo $row['list_name']; 
                    echo "</a></td><td>"; 
                    echo $row['date_made']; 
                    echo "</td></tr>";
                }
                echo("</table");
            }
        ?>

        </div>
```

After clicking Create I get the following result:

[image]

The displayed data is completely accurate. However, when I click the Create New List button again, the formatting of the div is distorted. Moreover, I can no longer see the categories and the to do divs after clicking on their buttons.

[image]

This is what I get now after clicking the categories button. The yellow div is no where in sight (same thing happens after clicking the to-do's button).

[image]

I know this is a very long post, but I couldn't explain the problem clearly without showing you all the screenshots of the site and the code. Could someone please point out where I've been going wrong? Why can't I see my categories and to do's divs after data is displayed? Why does the create new list form get distorted? I've been trying to solve this for a week - any and all help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a missing '>' in my code. Everything else was fine. I accidentally overlooked closing the  tag properly.